# Taiwanese/Hokkien For Kids: 我的面真古錐

Tags: hokkien

I came across a website about five or six years ago teaching Taiwanese/Hokkien for kids.

I believe the title was:
我的面真古錐

And it went something like:

> 我的面真古錐
> 兩蕊目睭

---

Actually looking online the entire thing should go something like this:
[高雄市路竹區三埤國民小學附設幼兒園](https://class.kh.edu.tw/2008/page/view/28?cat=19)

> 我的面真古錐，
> 兩蕊目睭大大蕊，
> 一个喙，一枝鼻，
> 耳仔有一對，
> 通人攏呵咾，
> 我的面真古錐。

I just can't seem to find the mp3 that it came with before?

Any ideas?

Comment: You can contact the school through its Facebook page - https://www.facebook.com/sanpikindy

Answer (score 1):

part of the song is in
[阿妹仔真古錐 律動版](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YD9Y0Rc3gs)

related words like 二蕊目睭大大蕊, 一對大耳仔大大對

Comment: Good effort. But this video is not the same as the one sought by the OP.